# Failed to select a version for the requirement `rand = "^0.9.0"`

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I am getting this error every time while running `cargo build`:

```
error: failed to select a version for the requirement `rand = "^0.9.0"`
candidate versions found which didn't match: 0.8.5, 0.8.4, 0.8.3, ...
location searched: crates.io index
required by package `guessing_game v0.1.0 (D:\Adwait\Rust\project\guessing_game)`
```

`Cargo.toml` looks like this:

```ini
[package]
name = "guessing_game"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
rand = "0.9.0"
```

Comment: I could know it now. As I am a beginner in rust.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This error is caused because there is no version `0.9.0` available. Update it to `0.8.0`. Cargo.toml should look like this.

```ini
[package]
name = "guessing_game"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
rand = "0.8.0"
```

Answer (score 7):

I experienced this myself, I believe the confusion is stemming from the [tutorial on Rust](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch02-00-guessing-game-tutorial.html) mentioning 0.9.0 as an example to understand upgrading Rust crates.

I'm not sure why they chose that example, since it doesn't exist. Would be a better idea to do 0.7.x being upgraded to 0.8.0 if you're new to Rust and want to play around with upgrading Rust crates.

Comment: can confirm it's still there and the reason i'm here. seems they should start with 0.8.0 and get the user to update to 0.8.5

Comment: I checked today (8/16/2023) the aforementioned tutorial has been updated to use `rand=0.8.5`

Comment: The book "The Rust Programming Language, 2nd Edition"(2023) has `rand=0.9.0`. But the online book has `rand=0.8.5`.

Answer (score 6):

Another possible reason for getting an error like this is that your compiler is outdated and the new version of the library targets the new compiler. Update your toolchain with `rustup update`.

I have a project that used clap 4.2, but which refused to compile on another computer with an error like this.